# C++: namespace conflict between extern "C" and class member

Tags: c++, c, namespaces, conflict, extern

I stumbled upon a rather exotic c++ namespace problem:

condensed example:

```
 extern "C" {
 void solve(lprec * lp);
 }

 class A {
 public:
    lprec * lp;
    void solve(int foo);
 }

 void A::solve(int foo)
 {
     solve(lp);
 }
```

I want to call the c function solve in my C++ member function A::solve. The compiler is not happy with my intent:

```
  error C2664: 'lp_solve_ilp::solve' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'lprec *' to 'int'
```

Is there something I can prefix the solve function with? C::solve does not work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To call a function in the global namespace, use:

```
::solve(lp);
```

This is needed whether the function is `extern "C"` or not.

Answer (score 2):

The C functions are in the global namespace. So try

```
::solve(lp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try `::solve`

Answer (score 1):

Simply `::solve(lp)`. Note you also need a semicolon after your class declaration.